Matlab code for solving inhomogeneous 1D heat equation using Crank-Nicolson
I'm trying to solve the 1D heat equation using Crank-Nicolson in Matlab.
The problem is, my numerical solution is not the same as the exact solution. (I already checked the plots and their shapes are different.)
I think my problem is that I have no idea how to deal with the $F_{k}^{n+1}$ term in the code.
IBVP: $v_{t} = nu*v_{xx} + x^{3}e^{t} - 9xe^{t}$ and the initial and boundary conditions are all written in the code below.
My Crank-Nicolson scheme: $-ru_{k+1}^{n+1} + (2+2r)u_{k}^{n+1} - ru_{k+1}^{n+1} = ru_{k+1}^{n} + (2-2r)u_{k}^{n} + ru_{k-1}^{n} + \triangle t(F_{k}^{n} + F_{k}^{n+1})$
L = 1; % final space(1D)
T = 1; % final time

x_interval_num = 10;
delta_x = L/x_interval_num;
delta_t = delta_x^2;
t_interval_num = T/delta_t;

x_grids = linspace(0, L, x_interval_num + 1)';
t_grids = linspace(0, T, t_interval_num + 1);

u = zeros(length(x_grids), length(t_grids));

% initial condition
u(:, 1) = x_grids.^3;

% boundary conditions
u(1, :) = 0;
u(end, :) = exp(t_grids);

nu = 3/2;
r = nu*delta_t/delta_x^2;

% Crank-Nicolson scheme
A = diag(-r * ones(length(x_grids)-1, 1), 1) + diag((2 + 2 * r) * ones(length(x_grids), 1)) + diag(-r * ones(length(x_grids) - 1, 1), -1);
B = diag(r * ones(length(x_grids)-1, 1), 1) + diag((2-2*r) * ones(length(x_grids), 1)) + diag(r * ones(length(x_grids) - 1, 1), -1);

for n = 1:length(t_grids)-1
    b = B*u(:, n) + delta_t*((x_grids.^3)*exp(t_grids(n)) - 9*x_grids*exp(t_grids(n)) + (x_grids.^3)*exp(t_grids(n+1)) - 9*x_grids*exp(t_grids(n+1)));
    
    u(:, n+1) = A\b;

    % update the boundary conditions
    u(1, n+1) = 0; % left boundary condition
    u(end, n+1) = exp(t_grids(n+1)); % right boundary condition
end

% exact solution
v = x_grids.^3*exp(t_grids);


@JeanMarie I think there is no problem at that part tho... For the matrix A, the entries on the main diagonal have to be 2+2r and the subdiagonal entries have to be -r. Similarly, for the matrix B, the entries on the main diagonal have to be 2-2r and the subdiagonal entries have to be r.

Indeed, I hadn't realized ! I remove my remark.

You need to handle the boundary conditions differently... You change the linear system so that the boundary conditions hold, you cannot just set the boundary conditions after you solve the system.
